# Error in updating profile with image using mongoose and cloudinary

Tags: javascript, express, file-upload, cloudinary, express-fileupload

```
 updateProfile: async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const update = req.body;
        const id = req.params.id;

        if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
            return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
        }


        const image = req.files.profileImage;

        const cloudFile = await upload(image.tempFilePath);
        const profileImage = cloudFile.url

        console.log('Loging cloudfile', profileImage)

        await User.updateOne(id, { update }, { profileImage }, { new: true },
            function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                if (doc) {
                    return res.status(200).send({ sucess: true, msg: 'Profile updated successful' })
                }
            });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message });
    }

}
```

But I'm getting an error of `"Callback must be a function, got [object Object]"`

I have tried to $set: update and $set: profileImage but still not working.

So the image successful upload into the cloudinary but the update for mongoose is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Upon brief research into the issue, I think you are feeding the arguments in wrong. Objects can be confusing but not to worry.

Your code is:

```js
await User.updateOne(id, { update }, { profileImage }, { new: true }
```

However, I believe it should be something more like:

```js
await User.updateOne({id: id}, { profileImagine: profileImage, new: true },
```

The API reference annotates use of the function as:

```
const filter = { name: 'John Doe' };
const update = { age: 30 };

const oldDocument = await User.updateOne(filter, update);
oldDocument.n; // Number of documents matched
oldDocument.nModified; // Number of documents modified
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it coming Clea....but what about the update const I had define which is carrying other user data.

Comment: Yes you can add more data to that. For example, const update = { age:30, name: Jake, type: 1 }